# Mysql Database issues with Character Set

Tags: database, wordpress, xampp

how to change utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_ci on xampp ? i want to change from all together. when i put site live it make problem to import/export data due-to "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci". how to solve it permanently ?
[please check the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZYZB.jpg) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a procedure to convert tables and its columns of a database.
hope to be useful.

https://gist.github.com/hosseinm1997/3bbbec3fc574287c752754db0201abfd

**Update:**
[image: Check this screen shot first]

- Copy contents of procedure as I mentioned in above gist.
- Select your database.
- Select sql tab.
- Paste the contents into the text area.
- The click Go.

Now the procedure created.

- Clear the text area and paste this command into:

  `changeAllCollations('yourdbname','utf8mb4' , 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' , true);`
- Specify *your db name* , *charater set* and *collation*
- Click Go
- That's it.

Comment: will you please send details. where should i add that file ? change_all_collations.sql

Comment: @javed sorry I updated the documentation. Check it again